# Fluid statics and pressure

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics, density, equilibrium

Consider a fluid filled in a cylindrical container, height $h$ and area of cross-section $a$. The pressure at the bottom will be:

$$p_0+\rho gh$$

but not

$$p_0+\rho gh+\frac{mg}{a}$$ where $m$ is the mass of fluid in the container and $\rho$ being its density. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

We know that, at a depth $h$ below the surface of water, pressure will be exerted by the atmosphere and the weight of water present till that level $h$, so pressure should be $P_h = (P_o + \frac{mg}{a})$

**BUT:** $\rho g h =\frac{mg}{a}$

**Proof:**

$m = \rho V$, where $\rho$ is density, $V$ is volume

We know that, $V = ah \implies m = \rho ah$

Therefore, $\frac{mg}{a} = \frac{(\rho a h) g}{a} = \rho g h$

This proves that $\boxed{P_h = P_o + \rho g h}$

Answer (score 0):

This is because $\rho gh$ is itself the pressure due to the liquid on the bottom of the container.

=>$$\rho gh=\frac{mgh}{v}$$
=>$$\rho gh=\frac{mg}{a}\ \ (since\  h\times a=v)$$

As you can see you counted the term twice.